Solving differential equation with mixed partials
Lets take differential equation
$$u_{tt}+2u_{tx}-3u_{xx}=0$$
where $-\infty < x < \infty$, $-\infty < t < \infty$ and the boundary conditions are $u(0,x) = \phi(x)$, $\;u_{t}(0,x) = \psi(x)$.
I knew the metod of separation of variables, but here I feel, I need to use another metod. What will be the assumption of the solution form here and next steps which help me to solve this problem?

Does this answer your question?

@Morten This gives me some hint but my equation has coefficients $2$, $-3$ and I don't know how to evaluate it.

This may also help.

$u(t,x)=F(t+x)+G(x-3t)$; $u(0,x) = \phi(x)$; $F(x)+G(x)=\phi(x)$; $;u_{t}(0,x) = \psi(x)$; $F'(x)-3G'(x)=\psi(x)$; $F(x)-3G(x)=\int_{x_0}^x \psi(x)$

$F(x)=\dfrac{3\phi(x)+\int_{x_0}^x \psi(x)}{4}$; $G(x)=\dfrac{\phi(x)-\int_{x_0}^x \psi(x)}{4}$; $u(t,x)=\dfrac{3\phi(t+x)+\phi(x-3t)+\int_{x-3t}^{t+x} \psi(x)}{4}$

The answer given as reason to close the question is similar, but in no way is answered as read in the title. The answer given as similar doesn't get the point on how to manage arbitrary functions as IC. Even the link given by @Gonçalo approaches better.
